# Directly Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I need to create an OpenSSL connection where I can directly read/write handshake data. The reason is the handshake data will be transported in a UDP connection (DTLS is not an option, because the data is not directly in the datagram, but inside another protocol packets, [EAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) if you're curious). So far, I've created an OpenSSL connection but I've not even been able to read the client's handshake to send to the server.

In my research I've found I need a Memory BIO to read/write to the connection, but cannot figure out how to extract the handshake data. Here's how I initialize the **client** connection:

```
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);

ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
```

I've tried doint `SSL_connect`, to initiate the handshake:

```
int ret = SSL_connect(ssl);
```

But returns `-1`, and doing `SSL_get_error(ssl, res)` I get an error code `2`, then I execute `ERR_error_string` with that code and get:

```
error:00000002:lib(0):func(0):system lib
```

Also, if I use `SSL_do_handshake` instead of `SSL_connect` I get exactly the same error.

I've been able to set a OpenSSL connection over TCP, but have never done this with Memory BIOs, so any help with this would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See Dr. Henson's answer at [Alternative Interface that doesn't use Sockets?](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Alternative-Interface-that-doesn-t-use-Sockets-td31483.html) Also see [openssl bio "shared memory"](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+bio+"shared+memory").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally I get it to work, I was in the right way:

The function `SSL_set_connect_state(ssl)` is needed to tell the connection to be prepared for the handshake init. Then, we call `SSL_do_handshake(ssl)` to start the handshake. This function will return `-1` because the handshake was not finished, but we can actually read from the client ssl connection BIO writer and send the data using the protocol we want (in my case, EAP RADIUS packets over UDP).

**Client**

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);

ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_connect_state(ssl); 

SSL_do_handshake(ssl); // This will return -1 (error) as the handshake is not finished, we can ignore it.

char buf[4096];
BIO_read(wbio, buf, 4096); // Read from BIO, put data in buffer

// Then use data in buffer to send to the server
```

The server, in the other hand, should be configured using the credential and private key. Also, instead of `SSL_set_connect_state()` we should use `SSL_set_accept_state()` as the server will wait for the client's handshake hello. Then, we simply write the client handshake hello data to the server BIO reader:

**Server**

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_server_method()); // This is the server!
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);

ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_accept_state(ssl); // The server uses SSL_set_accept_state

// Here we get the data from the client suppose it's in the variable buf
// and write it to the connection reader BIO.
BIO_write(rbio, buf, strlen(buf));

if (!SSL_is_init_finished(ssl)) {
    SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
}
```

We can use the the `SSL_is_init_finished(ssl)` function to check if the handshake was done, and while it is not done we call `SSL_do_handshake(ssl)`, and then read again from the BIO_writer to send data to the client.

This process between client and server should be done until the connection is done (i.e. `SSL_is_init_finished(ssl)` returns `true`).

Then, after the handshake is done, you can send *secure* data between client/server, by using the `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` functions. Hope this short explanation is useful for someone!

Comment: How did you do that? My server side answers with an error "Unexpected message". Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/7717ea7928b481258374

Comment: Nevermind, I've found this example: http://www.roxlu.com/2014/042/using-openssl-with-memory-bios
It works and it is amazingly useful :)

Comment: hello, i think im trying to do the same thing as you are here, could you help me? my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702893/designing-an-eap-tls-client-hello-message

Comment: how did you handle the server_hello response on the client side? Did you write it into rbio and use SSL_do_handshake() ? I am struggling at that point

Comment: Yes, you should do that in both sides until `SSL_is_init_finished(ssl)` returns `true`!

Comment: Another example of using memory BIO's : https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca

Comment: Sorry for necroing, Sergio do you have a full example please? I'm trying to implement something very similar, to this but I have no joy on the server side. I read the hello from the client, I write it in with BIO_write, check for init_finish, then try to do a BIO_read so I can send back data to client, but I always end up with Error Want Read and not sure what I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
// Connect the TCP socket (this is client side)
int sock = tcp_connect(host, port);

// Create BIO around the connected TCP socket 
BIO *sbio = BIO_new_socket(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(ssl,sbio,sbio); 

int ret = SSL_connect(ssl);
```

Think of BIO as a wrap around the socket. For client side, you have to give it a socket that is connected to the desired host and port using connect(...) call. For server side, just use the socket that is returned from accept(...) call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I pointed out in the question, I'm not using a TCP connection, but EAP packets over RADIUS (udp) and need to use Memory BIOs.