# SSL_do_handshake gets error wrong version number

Tags: c++, openssl

I have made a programmer following this:
[Directly Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio)

But now the function call SSL_do_handshake gets the error wrong version number, do you have any idea?

Here is the sample code.

client,

```
SSL_set_bio(pssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_connect_state(pssl); 

SSL_do_handshake(pssl); 
length = BIO_read(wbio, buffer, length);
```

server,

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(global_sslctx , "cacerts.pem" , NULL);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file( global_sslctx , "cert.pem"    , SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(  global_sslctx , "cert.pem"    , SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
BIO_write(SSL_get_wbio(pssl) , pdata , length);

if (!SSL_is_init_finished(pssl)) {
    SSL_do_handshake(pssl);
    printf("%s" ,ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
}
```

And i have dumped the momery data of the client,

16 03 01 00 de 01 00 00 da 03 01 9b dc 1e ef 4d f6 74 96 9b 8a 3f c0 3f de 37 4c 1b fa d7 d8 04 12 79 f9 bf 92 38 d8 59 c0 4f b4 00 00 68 c0 14 c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 39 00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00

Comment: How do you know there was an error at all? You're just *assuming* it.

Comment: printf("%s" ,ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));

Comment: You're printing that unconditionally. What made you think there was an error to print?

Comment: @EJP Because i can read the handshake data from the BIO of the server.

Comment: And that tells you what? As opposed to the result of SSL_do_handshake(), which you are ignoring?

Comment: @EJP Yes,it tells me WRONG VERSION NUMBER. The return value of SSL_do_handshake() is 0xfffffff , and i called SSL_get_error() it returns 2.

Comment: Well thanks for clearing that up. Impossible to tell with the code you've posted. How about posting the real code?

Comment: @EJP Read code? you mean all the code of the program? It is too large to read.

Comment: @iDebD_gh No,not that.

Comment: `BIO_write(SSL_get_wbio(pssl) , pdata , length);` returns an int, the number of bytes written to the BIO. Check that number, you're just assuming you have an error. `SSL_do_handshake` will return -1 if the handshake has not been finished, simply keep reading/writing until `SSL_is_init_finished` returns true.

Comment: I mean the real code that tested whether SSL_do_handshake() returned non-zero and so (a) printed the value you've stated here, and (b) called ERR_get_error() conditionally, instead of (c) ignoring the value, (d) not printing it, which provides no grounds for your assertion that it returned a non-zero value, and (e) calling ERR_get_error() unconditionally as your present code does, which isn't valid.