# OpenSSL with raw sockets for EAP-TLS

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I want to design an EAP-TLS client. As the protocol works on the ethernet layer, I am using raw sockets in C and designing the handshake step by step. I wanted to get the TLS data into the packet i designed using OpenSSL. The examples I found online used SSL_Connect() with a socket descriptor and sent the data. I however want to copy the data into the buffer i will send using the raw sockets. Is there any way to do this ? Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like `SSL_Connect()` does everything you want it to do. Why can't you just copy the implementation? If you want to do it as a learning exercise Why cant you just create a packed struct full of the information you want and just `write(fileDesc, struct ptr, sizeof(struct))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have everything in your own buffer and not send directly to the socket you have to use not a file descriptor, but a memory BIO as the lower layer for SSL and then you can use the usual SSL_ functions on top of it. You might have a look at [Directly Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio). A working implementation you'll find in [AnyEvent::Handle](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-7.07/lib/AnyEvent/Handle.pm). Although this is Perl the usage of the BIO_ functions is the same.

Comment: Good answer. I thought about that post immediately (and all the trouble that fellow had).

Comment: thank you for the reference! i wonder how i missed that question.