# Read TLS data from buffer into OpenSSL

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

Hello :) I'm trying to design an EAP-TLS client. I designed the TLS_client_hello as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio), but now I cannot figure out how to read the reply of the server into the same SSL context for further processing (certificate valdiation/key exchange). I am using raw sockets for designing the packets and am reading from the open socket into a char[] array. This is  what I have done so far:

```
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
    SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
    SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
    readbytes = BIO_read(wbio, buf, BUF_SIZ); //client_hello generated

   // different function,
   readbytes = BIO_write(rbio, temp, numbytes); // using the same BIO as above, temp contains the server_hello data
```

`

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far and mention what is not working.

Comment: Done! I cannot figure out how to get OpenSSL to read the data I receive from the server. I tried copying it into the BIO and using SSL_read(), but did not work.

Comment: You need to call `SSL_do_handshake`. Basically you need to repeat your operations till `SSL_do_handshake` returns 1 which indicate the handshake is complete. Have a look at https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_do_handshake.html

Comment: so after I write the new data into the BIO, i need to call SSL_do_handshake ?

Comment: Yes and then u will have to call ur read/write functions again for the handshake to progress till `SSL_do_handshake` returns 1 to indicate the handshake is complete.

Comment: I tried doing this, but OpenSSL outputs only 7 bytes in response to the above data, and gives an `Alert: Protocol version`

Comment: Please add your latest code.