# OpenSSL generates TLS-alert: unsupported_protocol

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, wireshark

I am trying to build an EAP-TLS client. I am using OpenSSL to build the TLS part of the data. Since EAP works on lower layers, I have used memory BIOs with OpenSSL to send information to Freeradius server using raw sockets. This is my code to generate client hello

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);
SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
readbytes = BIO_read(wbio, buf, BUF_SIZ);
```

and this is what i tried to do to read the reply of the server into the same `ssl`:

```
BIO_write(rbio, temp, numbytes);
SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
readbytes = BIO_read(wbio, read, BUF_SIZ); // read is a buffer
```

however, when i try to send a packet using the data held in read, wireshark shows the packet as:[image] Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this due to improper configuration of the RADIUS server? Or am I making a mistake in reading the data? According to what I read, SSL_do_handshake should be called till all the handshake steps are completed, so I dont think that there is a mistake there. Thanks a lot! Full packet sequence(use filter EAP) : http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/453553/eap-tls.pcapng

Comment: I've deleted my response because I did not read you question correctly. Why do you do SSL_handshake again when reading the reply of the server? And maybe you should give a pcap of the whole dialog instead of only an image from wireshark without any context of the previous packets.

Comment: edited :) and I don't know how to proceed, that is why tried SSL_do_handshake(), it also seemed logical. Am i going wrong there ?

Comment: I did not look at the picture of the pcap because a pcap file as data not as a picture would be better and I don't want to give out my email just to access the file. Apart from that, "man SSL_handshake: ... If the connection is in client mode, the handshake will be started". So it does not complete an existing handshake, it will start a new one which is maybe not what the server expects. Only if the BIO is non-blocking you might need to call it again to continue with the handshake, but you must make sure to properly react to SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE) before calling it again.

Comment: okay, so how do I get the server data to the ssl context?

Comment: I cannot see your full code, but since you are using your own buffer (BIO_s_mem) as the underlying BIO you have to write the output BIO to the server if there is something in it and fill the input BIO with new data from the server if you get SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ before you can call SSL_handshake again. And of course you should only repeat calls to SSL_handshake as long as it returns error.

Comment: After generating the client_hello data, I write the output BIO to the server. I then proceed to put the response in the input BIO, as you can see above. So after this I should check if get_ssl_error(ssl) returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ? If it returns that, use SSL_do_handshake(ssl)? If  it doesn't then what? I'm sorry I'm not getting what you're trying to convey.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you not just guess that you might need to call SSL_handshake, read data into the buffer etc, but that you should check and act according to the errors returned by SSL_handshake. E.g. stop doing handshake if there is no more error and if you get SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ feed data into it - even if you've just put data into the BIO. It might just need more data to continue with the handshake. So check the return code every time and behave according to the return code, that's what the return code is for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenSSL Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio)