# using TLS without sockets

Tags: c#, ssl

I have an embedded device running [mbed TLS (PolarSSL)](https://tls.mbed.org/) This device needs to communicate with a server. this server is written in C# and does some things with the incoming data, in other words TLS cannot directly listen on a socket, i have a method which feeds the data.

For as far as I know the normal C# library only works directly on top of a socket so I am at a loss of what to do. I know this sounds strange, and it is but I have absolutely no idea how to explain it any better. (my colleagues mentioned something about uip)

So what TLS library is there to create a server without needing to use sockets.

I am trying to use TLS 1.2 with PSK and AES128-GCM.

Comment: You might use OpenSSL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio

Comment: @SteffenUllrich seems promising, i'll take a look thanks :D

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it seems the openssl has no AES-128 GCM unfortunately would have been a great library otherwise:(

Comment: Sure it does: AES128-GCM-SHA256.  Which version of OpenSSL did you try?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this is the one i found: http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes, this uses an old version of OpenSSL. Support for TLS1.2 and GCM ciphers needs at least version 1.0.1 (current is 1.0.2). Try https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net

Comment: @SteffenUllrich does not seem to have tls 1.2 or aes gcm, odd, maybe i'm looking in the wrong place but thanks anyway, i will surely keep an eye on it for further changes. if you happen to know an other let me know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a virtual socket class that exposes the Socket class API and inside handles the communication with the C# server. Then you could use this virtual socket with your TLS library.

Of course you would need to make sure that the API behaves exactly as the Socket API, the synchronous methods need to be synchronous, the asynchronous methods need to be asynchronous, you need too throw the same exceptions as the Socket API etc.

I hope this helps,
Dragan