# Use openssl for encapsulated packet

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I want to develop a ssl server to create a secure connection using Openssl in C++. But I receive Client Hello message encapsulated in another protocol packet. Example packet:

```
Simple TCP Packet =  TCP Headers | TCP Data 
TCP Data          =  Protocol Headers | Protocol Data | Client Hello
```

How can I extract Client Hello from packet and How can I use it in Openssl accept?

My Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* 
    ------------------ START Initialize Server ------------------
     */

    int serverfd, clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in vir_serv_addr, cli_addr;

    serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero((char *) &vir_serv_addr, sizeof (vir_serv_addr));

    vir_serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    vir_serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    vir_serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);

    bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *) &vir_serv_addr, sizeof (vir_serv_addr));
    listen(serverfd, 5);
    socklen_t client = sizeof (cli_addr);
    clientfd = accept(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*) & client);

    /*
    ------------------- END Initialize Server ------------------- 
     */

    /* 
    ------------------ START SSL ------------------
     */

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    FILE* certF = fopen("server-cert.pem", "r");
    X509* cert = PEM_read_X509(certF, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    FILE* keyF = fopen("server-key.pem", "r");
    EVP_PKEY* key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(keyF, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SSL_CTX* context = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_server_method());

    SSL_CTX_use_certificate(context, cert);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(context, key);
    SSL_CTX_check_private_key(context);

    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(context, 1);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(context, 4);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(context, "ca-cert.pem", "");

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(context);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientfd);

    int r = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if (r != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        int err_SSL_get_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, r);

        switch (err_SSL_get_error) {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                printf("%d", 0);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                printf("%d", 1);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                printf("%d", 2);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                printf("%d", 3);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d", -1);
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
    ------------------- END SSL ------------------- 
     */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't speak TLS directly on the wire but instead the TLS frames are encapsulated in some other protocol you cannot use the file descriptor backend of OpensSL (`SSL_set_fd`). Instead you have to use the BIO backend (`SSL_set_bio`) with some memory BIO. With a memory BIO OpenSSL will not read/write the data by itself from/to the file descriptor but instead read/write to some memory location.

For more details see 
[Directly Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio)

Comment: In other words, you need to do your own socket I/O to handle the encapsulating protocol, and then use OpenSSL's BIO API to pass encrypted TLS data to OpenSSL during read operations, and receive encrypted TLS data from OpenSSL during write operations.