# How can TLS api SSL_write() be made to work on top of SCTP protocol?

Tags: ssl, openssl, rhel7, sctp

By means of SCTP socket api `sctp_sendmsg()`, parameters like streamNumber, ppid, orderedDelivery are configurable before sending out a message over transport.

While i was trying to have TLS integrated to SCTP code using `SSL_Write()` api, the flexibility to choose the stream on which the message is send out(& other SCTP specific params as well) is lost, and default values are always associated to the SCTP params.

My doubt is, when using TLS, how is the SCTP flexibility achieved ?

Comment: You can use the [BIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753221/openssl-read-write-handshake-data-with-memory-bio) interface to interface with memory buffers instead of sockets and then exchange the data between the memory buffer and the socket in your own custom way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich BIO is something yet to be tried out. 
However google search gave me some leads on the SCTP structure format, and i found a sleeker solution.

I was able to use the `setsockopt()` along with the `SCTP_DEFAULT_SEND_PARAM` flag to set the `sctp_sndrcvinfo.sinfo_stream` to the required stream number before calling the `SSL_write()` api. Other parameters can also be modified in the same fashion(didnt try though).

Thought of sharing the same.